# Trigger/activate the RowEditor from bean for a primefaces In-Cell editing enabled p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces `p:dataTable` with [InCell editing enabled](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf) and want to trigger/activate the RowEditor for the newly added row.

**Excerpt of XHTML**

```
<p:commandButton id="btnAddEntry" value="Add new row" actionListener="#{myBean.addNewCar}" ... update="carTable growl" process="@this carTable ..."/>

<p:dataTable id="carTable" var="car" value="#{myBean.cars}" ... editable="true">  
        <p:column ...>  
            <p:cellEditor>
                ...
            </p:cellEditor>  
        </p:column>
    ...
        <p:column ...>  
                <p:rowEditor />  
        </p:column>
    ...         
</p:dataTable>
```

Here is what i have so far for the **bean method**:

```
public void addNewCar() {

    Car newCar = new Car();
    cars.add(newCar);

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIComponent uiTable = ComponentUtils.findComponent(facesContext.getViewRoot(), "carTable");
    DataTable table = (DataTable) uiTable;

    final AjaxBehavior behavior = new AjaxBehavior();    
    RowEditEvent rowEditEvent = new RowEditEvent(uiTable, behavior, table.getRowData());
    rowEditEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES);
    table.broadcast(rowEditEvent);
}
```

i don't know

1. if this is the correct approach
2. in case yes, which object to pass to the constructor `RowEditEvent(UIComponent component, Behavior behavior, Object object)` as the 3rd parameter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have only one data table in the facelet try to use this

```
oncomplete="jQuery('.ui-datatable-data tr').last().find('span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){jQuery(this).click()});
```

Add this to the command button. This should work.

Comment: jQuery is what the primefaces team uses to implement his framework, and is a very powerful tool =)

Answer (score 6):

I used the execute(..) method of class RequestContext in my create method. This allowed me to first calculate the index of the row to go into edit mode and to include it dynamically in the javascript:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("jQuery('span.ui-icon-pencil').eq(" + rowToEditIndex + ").each(function(){jQuery(this).click()});");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I pass in hardcoded values for rowToEditIndex , it seems to work. But if is a variable, doesn't seems to work. Any idea why? Couldn't figure out.

Comment: Have you checked the variables values? log them and then run the resulting script manually in your browser to see whether it works, then it'll work as well using RequestContext (that's how I did it)

Comment: Yes. I did a printout. The variable is correct. But I use this at the RowEditEvent. Not sure if that causes issue? Just my suspicion.

Comment: I was checking the same problem and I found this solution useful but according to the old comments there was a problem when try to get the row index dynamically, anyway I share my solution for someone who try something like this. The solution was just as the comments say but assign the value to a int and then you can  reference in order to get the row index  `int selectedIndex = dataTable.getRowIndex() + 1;
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("jQuery('span.ui-icon-pencil').eq(" + selectedIndex + ").each(function(){jQuery(this).click()});"); `

Answer (score 1):

You can add an unique styleClass to the dataTable, and one javascript function in the commandButton:

So add to the table:

```
styleClass="myTable"
```

And to the button:

```
oncomplete="$('.myTable tbody.ui-datatable-data tr:last-child td span.ui-row-editor span.ui-icon-pencil').click()"
```

And your code will look like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnAddEntry" value="Add new row" actionListener="#{myBean.addNewCar}" ... update="carTable growl" process="@this carTable ..." oncomplete="$('.myTable tbody.ui-datatable-data tr:last-child td span.ui-row-editor span.ui-icon-pencil').click()"/>

<p:dataTable styleClass="myTable" id="carTable" var="car" value="#{myBean.cars}" ... editable="true">  
        <p:column ...>  
            <p:cellEditor>
                ...
            </p:cellEditor>  
        </p:column>
    ...
        <p:column ...>  
                <p:rowEditor />  
        </p:column>
    ...         
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution aims to resolve a few drawbacks of the original answer of:

```
oncomplete="jQuery('.ui-datatable-data tr').last().find('span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){jQuery(this).click()});"
```

The above statement retrieves all "tr" elements which are descendants (at any level) of elements with the ".ui-datatable-data" class.  The potential issues with that are:

1. As mentioned by @Gnappuraz, if there are multiple p:datatable's in the document, this statement will choose the last table.
2. Additionally, I ran into a problem where even with one datatable, a column with a p:selectOneRadio component will also render a html table (that contains "tr" elements).  In this case the selector chooses the last "tr" for the p:selectOneRadio's table, rather than the p:datatable.
3. Not a problem, but the statement can be shortened to exclude the each() because of jQuery's [implicit iteration](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

What I ended up with was:

```
oncomplete="jQuery('#tableForm\\:table .ui-datatable-data > tr').last().find('span.ui-icon-pencil').click();"
```

This selector says - get the last "tr" element, which is a **direct** child of an element with class ".ui-datatable-data", which is also a descendant of the element with id "table" in form "tableForm".  In other words you can now have multiple p:datatables, and any include any components that render html tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
jQuery('#FormID\\:DataTableID\\:#{datatable.size()}\\:rowEditorID').find('span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){jQuery(this).click()});
```

worked well, no matter how many datatables in a same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several DataTable which each of them has an ID, then try to use one of these solutions:

```
Oncomplete="jQuery('#FrmID:TabViewI:mydataTableID'.replace(/:/g,'\\:')).find('span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){jQuery(this).click()});"
```

OR:

```
oncomplete="jQuery('#FrmID\\:TabViewID\\:mydataTableID').find('span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){jQuery(this).click()});"
```

This should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Execute a JQuery script on complete process :

```
oncomplete="editNewRow()"
```

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("keydown", ".ui-cell-editor-input input", function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $(this).closest("tr").find(".td-edition .ui-row-editor .ui-row-editor-check .ui-icon-check").click();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            function editNewRow() {
                $("#pim\\:invoiceRuleCretariaTable tbody:first tr:first .td-edition .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil").click();
            }
        </script>
```

The first function submit the addition action by press on "Enter" key

Answer (score 0):

Execute a JQuery script on complete process :

```
oncomplete="editNewRow()"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("keydown", ".ui-cell-editor-input input", function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $(this).closest("tr").find(".td-edition .ui-row-editor .ui-row-editor-check .ui-icon-check").click();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            function editNewRow() {
                $("#panel\\:carTable tbody:first tr:last .td-edition .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil").click();
            }
        </script>
```

The first function submit the addition action by press on "Enter" key

Answer (score 0):

In Primefaces 7

```
    UIComponent uiTable = JSFUtils.findComponent("productAttributeTable");
    DataTable table = (DataTable) uiTable;
    int selectedIndex = table.getRowIndex() + 1;
    PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("jQuery('span.ui-icon-pencil').eq(" + selectedIndex + ").each(function(){jQuery(this).click()});");
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve this is better to use styleClass and because for fix this it is necessary to use javascript, you need to check the html tags in your browser, because it seems that they change with the versions of primefaces. For vesion 6.1 I've put this on my bean:

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.execute("$('.styleEventosPlanPrestacion tbody.ui-datatable-data tr:first-child td div.ui-row-editor a.ui-row-editor-pencil').click()");
```

and In my .xhtml I've  put this:

```
<p:dataTable ... styleClass="styleEventosPlanPrestacion">
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answer that says to use a styleclass?

Comment: I've tried the prior solution but it wasn't working for me and then I've noticed the html tags have changed. That's why I've recommended to check them and I just wanted to contribute with the code for the last primefaces version. Anyone could have a problem if it don't care about the tags. Please, you just can't rate negative a valid answer just because your knowledge is higher than average or just because you didn't have the same trouble. It's not so easy for someone who is not familiar with JQuery.