# Edit row using Radio button and commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Can I use radio button to select a single row then edit some of data on that row then use 
commandButton to submit what I edit it in that row. I'm trying to edit username cell for now as test.
[image]

this a snap of my code:

Xadmin.xhtml

```
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

    <p:dataTable id="DT" value="#{Jadmin.messages}"
                 var="o"
                 selection="#{Jadmin.selectedUser}"
                 rowKey="#{o.id}"
                 style="margin-bottom:20px">

        <f:facet name="header">
            Users List
        </f:facet>

        <p:column selectionMode="single" />

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="id" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{o.id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>

            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="username" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:inputText value="#{o.username}"  />
        </p:column>


        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:commandButton  value="Update" action="#{Jadmin.update}" />

            <p:commandButton value="Delete"
                             action="#{Jadmin.delete}"
                             ajax="false"
                             update=":form:msgs"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
```

JadminBeans.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "Jadmin")
@SessionScoped
public class JadminBeans implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JadminController selectedUser;

    List<JadminController> userslist = new ArrayList<JadminController>();

    public List<JadminController> getMessages() {
        System.out.println("List<JadminController> getMessages()");
        userslist = JadminDAO.getAllUsers();
        return userslist;
    }

    public void delete() {
        //System.out.println(usr);
        //System.out.println(itemList.remove(item)+"!!");
        System.out.println("JadminBeans >> delete() ---------- id= ");
        JadminDAO.deleteUser(selectedUser);

    }

    public JadminController getSelectedUser() {
        return selectedUser;
    }

    public void setSelectedUser(JadminController selectedUser) {
        this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    }

    public void update() {
        //o=(JadminBeans) objct;
        JadminDAO.updateUser(selectedUser);
    }
}
```

JadminDAO.java

```
public static void deleteUser(JadminController user) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("delete from users where id=?");
        // Parameters start with 1
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, user.getId());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("JadminDAO >> deleteUser ----------");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("JadminDAO >> deleteUser----------- SQLException :(");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void updateUser(JadminController user) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update users username=?, password=?, permission=? where username=?");
        // Parameters start with 1
        //System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(user.getRegisteredon().getTime()));
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUsername());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getPermission());
        //preparedStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(user.getRegisteredon().getTime()));
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getUsername());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

JadminController.java

```
public class JadminController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username, password, permission;
    private long id;

    // Getters and setters.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Editable Datatable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) you don't need any command button to submit what you've edited.
As shown in the same link, inside in datatable is usually used a `selectOneMenu` instead of radioButton for making choices.

To use input element inside your datatable don't forget to put `<f:facet name="output"></f:facet>` and `<f:facet name="input"></f:facet>`

I hope it helps.

Comment: I need command button to delete a single row. my question is how can i use commandbutton to edit a single row ?

Comment: Do you mean inline edit row? Do you want replace the standard p:rowEditor with a commandButton and maintain behaviour?

Comment: that exactly what i mean. if possible ?

Comment: I suppose that is possible only using javascript. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821750/trigger-activate-the-roweditor-from-bean-for-a-primefaces-in-cell-editing-enable) could be useful, is not the same that you need but could be a good starting point.