# How to trigger row editor on a p:treeTable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I have an [editable `p:treeTable`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/edit.xhtml):

```
<p:treeTable ...
             editable="true">
  <p:column headerText="Name">
    <p:cellEditor>
      ...
    </p:cellEditor>
  </p:column>
  <p:column style="width:32px">
    <p:rowEditor />
  </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

I don't like the fact that I have to click the pencil icon to trigger the row editor. I tried to trigger the editor by selecting the first pencil's anchor at the first row in my browser's JavaScript console:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ui-row-editor-pencil")[0].click();
```

That does not work. Is there an other way to trigger the row editor using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you don't need to select and click the pencil's anchor, but the `span` within the anchor, so:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ui-row-editor-pencil span")[0].click();
```

I've added a hack to trigger row editing based on the row key, by adding the row key in the `styleClass` attribute of the `p:rowEditor`:

```
<p:treeTable nodeVar="node" ...>
  ...
  <p:column style="width:32px">
    <p:rowEditor styleClass="rowEditor-#{node.rowKey}"/>
  </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

This allows you to easily trigger editing by ID:

```
document.querySelector(".rowEditor-"+ rowKey +" .ui-row-editor-pencil span").click();
```

See also:

- [Trigger/activate the RowEditor from bean for a primefaces In-Cell editing enabled p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821750/trigger-activate-the-roweditor-from-bean-for-a-primefaces-in-cell-editing-enable)

Comment: Why not add a no-functional class attribute on the `p:rowEditor` and use that in the selection? And (if using jsf-2.2) did you check if passthrough attributes work on a `p:column`?

Comment: Thanks. Passthrough does not work. I've added the row key to a style class.