# Expand a specific row of a p:dataTable

Tags: primefaces

I have a screen where I have a list of items and an expansion button left. In the filter if the user enter with a specific information it will bring the same entire list BUT I need to expand the specific row.

```html
<p:rowExpansion>
    <p:dataTable var="inventoryPartsItems"
    value="#{partnerInventory.getInventoryItems(inventoryPart)}"
    emptyMessage="#{msgs.common_no_registries}" id="tableItems">
    <p:column style="width:16px">
        <p:rowToggler
            rendered="#{inventoryPartsItems.sapOperation != null}" />
    </p:column>
```

Comment: You might want to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909849/how-to-trigger-row-editor-on-a-ptreetable-using-javascript

Comment: Your code does not look okay to begin with though. Have a look here first https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml

Comment: It already works and I also have a button to expand/collapse all. I am not getting success to expand one line according the filter, list all itens but if enter with a specific PIN then I need to list all itens like before but expand just the line where I have this specific PIN

Comment: I could expand using this: expandedRow="#{partnerInventory.expandPartnerRow}">

But it expand all lines or collapse all lines because it get the last value from this return partnerInventory.expandPartnerRow, not line by line